# image is fixed other is relative

Tags: jquery, html, css

below is my code, In this code the image will be fixed within all sections but I need that the image will be fixed in first two section and after the third section, the image position will be relative and scrolling.

Right now I image is fixed in first two sections , but not scrolling in third please help me to find out to better solution.

Below my snippet :

```js
var windw = this;

$.fn.followTo = function ( pos ) {
    var $this = this,
        $window = $(windw);
    
    $window.scroll(function(e){
        if ($window.scrollTop() > pos) {
            $this.css({
                position: 'absolute',
                top: pos
            });
        } else {
            $this.css({
                position: 'fixed',
                top: 0
            });
        }
    });
};

$('#f').followTo('#third');
```

```css
section{
width:100%;
height:1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
<h1>first section</h1>
<img src="http://simform.solutions/HTML/silo/image/Bitmap.png" id="f">
</section>
<section>
<h1>2 section</h1>
</section>
<section id="third">
<h1>3 section</h1>
</section>
<section>
<h1>4 section</h1>
</section>
<section>
<h1>5 section</h1>
</section>
```

Comment: can you provide a working example of what you're trying to achieve ?

Comment: in this example small case fixed untill the last section after it's relative                 https://wocketwallet.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should calculate (`pos = $(pos).offset().top;`) the offset top of your element and then compare to window `scrollTop()` , because here you're passing only text id of your element

See below snippet :

```js
var windw = this;

$.fn.followTo = function ( pos ) {
    var $this = this,
        $window = $(windw);
    pos = $(pos).offset().top;
    
    $window.scroll(function(e){
        if ($window.scrollTop() > pos) {
            $this.css({
                position: 'absolute',
                top: pos
            });
        } else {
            $this.css({
                position: 'fixed',
                top: 0
            });
        }
    });
};

$('#f').followTo('#third');
```

```css
section{
width:100%;
height:1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
<h1>first section</h1>
<img src="http://simform.solutions/HTML/silo/image/Bitmap.png" id="f">
</section>
<section>
<h1>2 section</h1>
</section>
<section id="third">
<h1>3 section</h1>
</section>
<section>
<h1>4 section</h1>
</section>
<section>
<h1>5 section</h1>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are passing wrong parameter type (string) to followTo function

looks like you have to pass the `$('#third').position().top` (int value offset from top) e.g. `$('#f').followTo($('#third').position().top);`

or you can do it inside followTo e.g.:

```
$.fn.followTo = function ( elementSelector ) {
   var pos = $(elementSelector ).position().top
   ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified a little bit you script. I think the problem is your parameter need to be height value. Here is the modified version. Note that `#sec1` and `#sec2` is `id` of first 2 sections

```
var windw = this;

    $.fn.followTo = function () {
        var $this = this,
            $window = $(windw);
        var sectionHeight1 = $('#sec1').outerHeight(true);
        var sectionHeight2 = $('#sec2').outerHeight(true);
        var total = sectionHeight1+sectionHeight2;

        $window.scroll(function(e){
            if ($window.scrollTop() > total) {
                $this.css({
                    position: 'absolute',
                    top: total
                });
            } else {
                $this.css({
                    position: 'fixed',
                    top: 0
                });
            }
        });
    };

    $('#f').followTo();
```